# Missing threshold in the post processing section

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

There is no threshold under the post processing title for my current working file. If I open a new file, threshold appears as in right picture. It seems that I've changed some settings but I couldn't find. What can be the reason of this situation?

Note: I think this is related to settings, not objects, because I took the screenshots for newly added object in both files.

[image: without threshold]
[image: with threshold]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This panel changes depending on if your render engine is set to Cycles or Blender Render in the info bar at the top of the Blender window:

[image]

You have probably changed the render engine to Cycles in your current file, but in the new file it goes back to the default Blender Render.